# Novel or series of novels with aliens that can speed up

Tags: story-identification

So I just thought of a novel or a series, not sure (it was definitely an author's early work) in which humans are colonizing another planet. The plants and animals are pretty dangerous, so they've started with a colony on an island. The island has surprisingly few species. They later discover that this is because of the local super-predator. It lives in the water, there's a river that runs through the island. And the key thing is, it has an enzyme or something that is basically rocket fuel. The alien can Speed Up to ridiculous speeds. However, that's why it needs to be near the water - this can lead to overheating and it dying. There's also some political conflicts going on between the human settlers, and the protagonists build a separate enclave in a mountain, and they maybe have a small stream running through the middle room? In the second book, it turns out the aliens are almost sapient or something? In any case, we do have some chapters from the POV of the aliens. The humans start calling them Monsters or Demons or something, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's The Legacy of Heorot. The monsters are called Grendels. And I found it by finding Desiny's Road, also by Larry Niven, which I was reminded of while writing this ask.